# Regex on df output not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regular expression with the `preg_match` function in PHP to match the output of the **df** command in Linux. Note that I used a `define` macro to simplify the readability of the regular expression.

```
define("MATCH_DF",
    "/^(?P<filesystem>[0-9a-z\/]+)\s+" . 
    "(?P<blocks>[0-9]+)\s+" . 
    "(?P<used>[0-9]+)\s+" . 
    "(?P<avail>[0-9]+)\s+" . 
    "(?P<percent>[0-9]+%)\s+" .
    "(?P<mount>[0-9a-zA-Z\/]+)\s+$/");
```

For those who do not know, the output of the `df` command line looks like this...

```
Filesystem       1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        236520176   2863468 221642116   2% /
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Why isn't this working? I've narrowed the problem down to being something in my regular expression.

Comment: What output is `preg_match()` giving you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for some whitespace at the end of the string, of which there isn't any. You could swap the `+` quantifier for a `*` to make it optional, or remove it all together.

Try this regex...

```
define("MATCH_DF",
    "/^(?P<filesystem>[\da-z\/]+)\s+" . 
    "(?P<blocks>\d+)\s+" . 
    "(?P<used>\d+)\s+" . 
    "(?P<avail>\d+)\s+" . 
    "(?P<percent>\d+%)\s+" .
    "(?P<mount>[\da-zA-Z\/]+)$/");
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SJi2n2).

I also swapped your `[0-9]` for `\d`.

If you want to discard the numeric matches and just keep the named capturing groups...

```
$matches = array_diff_key($matches, array_values($matches));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/T5reUf).

Comment: @Michael I hope that's better than the [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1059786/) :).

Comment: Thanks! I looked at it for 12 minutes straight and never noticed I had left the space matching on the end.